# Permanently update ios deployement target version of react codegen

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have a simple project in react native with the last version. When I have try to run I get the following error for the FBReactNativeSpec :

[image: value is unavailable]

When I change the deployement target for the React-Codegen package to 12 it is working fine

[image: react codegen deployement target version]

But when I run the pod install command line, the target is reset to default, so 11. Does anyone know a way to set this value permanently ?